# Direct initialization with prvalue: Bug in MSVC?

Tags: c++, c++17, list-initialization, prvalue, direct-initialization

Consider the following code:

```cpp
struct S
{
    S(int, double) {}
    explicit S(const S&) {}
    explicit S(S&&) {}
};

void i_take_an_S(S s) {}

S i_return_an_S() { return S{ 4, 2.0 }; }

int main()
{
    i_take_an_S(i_return_an_S());
}
```

With the '-std=c++17' flag, both g++ and clang++ compile this code just fine. MSVC (with the /std:c++17 flag), however, reports

> "error C2664: 'void i_take_an_S(S)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'S' to 'S'"

as a compilation error, with the additional note

> "Constructor for struct 'S' is declared 'explicit'".

According to C++17's initialization rules ([Explanation of point 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast)) `S`'s copy constructor should not be considered for the initialization of the `S` parameter of `i_take_an_S`; `S(int, double)` should rather be selected as an exact match by direct-list-initialization.

Might this be a bug in MSVC?

Comment: The bug is not in the handling of `S{ 4, 2.0 }`.

Comment: MSVC might actually be the correct one here.  That said, I could see guaranteed copy elision applying here meaning no copy happens.

Comment: @NathanOliver I believe, MSVC is incorrect, since the standard guarantees copy/move elision here (returning prvalue and object initialization with prvalue). Moreover, if you swich standard to 11 in gcc or clang, it would complain about the explicit constructors.

Comment: Just asking - why would you ever want an explicit copy or move constructor?  Seems a crazy thing to even try.  In my experience, `explicit` is there to avoid unwanted conversions from other types.  (I know what it does and that it's legal, but have never wanted to  use it).

Comment: @TonyDelroy I was just experimenting with the initialization rules of C++17 (or greater) for my own educational purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, MSVC seems to be wrong here.

Generally, since C++17, the initialization rules are so that `S{ 4, 2.0 }` will directly initialize the parameter `S s` of the function. (mandatory copy elision)

There is however an exception. An implementation is allowed to introduce a copy in a function parameter or a return value if the class type has only deleted or trivial copy/move constructors and destructor (and at least one of the former non-deleted).

That you declare the copy and move constructor `explicit` doesn't change that they are copy/move constructors. Because you are not using `= default` to define them, they are not trivial. Therefore the special permission does not apply and it is wrong of MSVC to try to perform a copy.

Furthermore this special kind of copy ignores accessibility and overload resolution and therefore `explicit` shouldn't be relevant even if it was performed, see [[class.temporary]/3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.temporary#3).

---

When exactly copy elision is performed affects the ABI however, so if this is a defect in MSVC's ABI, then it might not be easily fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> Might this be a bug in MSVC?

Yes, MSVC is wrong in rejecting the code.

The operand `S{ 4, 2.0 }` of the return statement `return S{ 4, 2.0 }` is a prvalue of type `S` and from C++17 onwards due [mandatory copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), the parameter named `s` of function `i_take_an_S` is **constructed directly**(without using any copy/move ctor) from `S{ 4, 2.0 }`.

---

This can be seen from [copy elison](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision):

> Under the following circumstances, the compilers are required to omit the copy and move construction of class objects, even if the copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects. T**he objects are constructed directly into the storage where they would otherwise be copied/moved to**. The copy/move constructors need not be present or accessible:
>
> In a return statement, when the operand is a prvalue of the same class type (ignoring cv-qualification) as the function return type:
>
> ```
> T f()
> {
>    return T();
> }
>
> f(); // only one call to default constructor of T
> ```